# Что не так с моим списком?

Tags: c

Пытаюсь создать список и вывести его.

```
typedef struct WinProc      // Структура процессов windows
{
    char process_name[10];  // имя
    int ram;                // сколько оперативной памяти использует
    int percent0_100;       // насколько нагружает процессор
    struct WinProc *next;   // указатель на следующий элемент
} WinProc;

void push (WinProc **head, char name[10], int ram, int percent)
{
    // Создаем новый узел
    WinProc *tmp = (WinProc*) malloc(sizeof(WinProc));
    // Приписываем ему значения
    tmp->percent0_100 = name[10];
    tmp->ram = ram;
    tmp->percent0_100 = percent;
    // Присваиваем указателю tmp адрес предыдущего узла
    tmp->next = (*head);
    // Присваиваем указателю head адрес нового узла
    (*head) = tmp;
    // После выхода из функции переменная tmp будет уничтожена.
    // Получим список, в который будет вставлен новый элемент.
}

void printLinkedList(const WinProc *head)
{   // вывод содержимого списка
    while (head) {
        printf("%d ", head->process_name[10]);
        printf("%d ", head->ram);
        printf("%d ", head->percent0_100);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void main()
{
    WinProc* head = NULL;

    push(head, "proc1",10,10);
    push(head, "proc2",20,20);
    push(head, "proc3",30,30);

    printLinkedList(head);
}
```

Получаю *Segmentation fault*, будто я обращаюсь к недоступной для меня памяти.

Comment: У вас параметр функции `push` - это WinProc **, а передаете вы WinProc*

Comment: То есть передавайте первым параметром &head. Ну и еще что можно сказать - это работа со строками. присвоить через = нельзя, измените на копирование (через `strcpy/strncpy`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот Исправленный вариант

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct WinProc      // Структура процессов windows
{
    char process_name[10];  // имя
    int ram;                // сколько оперативной памяти использует
    int percent0_100;       // насколько нагружает процессор
    struct WinProc *next;   // указатель на следующий элемент
} WinProc;

void push (WinProc **head, char name[10], int ram, int percent)
{
    // Создаем новый узел
    WinProc *tmp = (WinProc*) malloc(sizeof(WinProc));
    // Приписываем ему значения
    memcpy(tmp->process_name, name, 10);
    tmp->ram = ram;
    tmp->percent0_100 = percent;
    // Присваиваем указателю tmp адрес предыдущего узла
    tmp->next = (*head);
    // Присваиваем указателю head адрес нового узла
    (*head) = tmp;
    // После выхода из функции переменная tmp будет уничтожена.
    // Получим список, в который будет вставлен новый элемент.
}

void printLinkedList(const WinProc *head)
{   // вывод содержимого списка
    while (head) {
        printf("%s ", head->process_name);
        printf("%d ", head->ram);
        printf("%d ", head->percent0_100);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
    WinProc* head = NULL;

    push(&head, "proc1",10,11);
    push(&head, "proc2",20,22);
    push(&head, "proc3",30,33);

    printLinkedList(head);
}
```

Что у нас тут изменено:

Функция `push` первым параметром имеет указатель на указатель соответственно вызов должен быть таким `push(&head,..`.

Неправильная работа со строками. вместо `tmp->percent0_100 = name[10];` должно быть `memcpy(tmp->process_name, name, 10);`.

Ну и ошибка при выводе строк. Вы их выводить как число `printf("%d ", head->process_name[10]);`. Должно быть `printf("%s ", head->process_name);`.

[Для проверки](https://ideone.com/pGleDv)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!